How can I keep the composer in iTerm2 always open for inputting commands?
Warp was banned in my company and I'm back using iTerm2. One thing I miss a lot is editing commands like in a text editor.
I know I can open the composer by using the shortcut shift + cmd + ., but it would be nice having the composer as the default command input.
Is it possible to keep the composer always opened somehow?
